# NumberFormatException String to Double to String

Tags: java, double, jvm

Tengo una pregunta relacionada con la **JVM** de java.

Tenemos un **double** en forma de **String** y lo queremos parsear a **double**, para ello quisimos comprobar si la `','` se parsea a `'.'` correctamente.
Si ejecutas este trozo de codigo:

`System.out.println(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("98,71")));`

saltará la exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "98,71"

En cambio si intentas parsearlo de esta forma no saltará ninguna excepcion:

```
double x = Double.parseDouble("23,34");

String result = String.valueOf(x);

System.out.println(result);
```

Digamos que el objetivo de todo esto es parsear a **double** un **numero** en formato **String** que está escrito con `','` y el numero, al recoger el **double** ya se parseará la `','` por `'.'` y más tarde ya parseo de nuevo el **double** a un **String** y el número tendrá un `'.'` en vez de una `','`.

Está claro que hay muchos caminos para hacer esto, pero mi objetivo con esta pregunta es saber por qué en el primer `System.out.println` que os he puesto da error de `NumberFormatException`.

***Adjunto prueba de que parsea correctamente en la opción 2.***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He probado los dos códigos y los 2 dan la excepción NumberFormatException y si cambias la coma por punto funcionan los 2. No veo que problema tienes.

Comment: Pues que la segunda opción no me da el NumberFormatException, me parsea bien el String a Double siendo una coma la separacion decimal, y por eso no entiendo que está pasando dentro de Java para que a veces salte y a veces no @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Comment: Yo he probado tu código y como digo, me ha dado el mismo fallo en los dos teniendo la coma y han funcionado los 2 poniendo el punto

Answer (score 2):

La funcion parseDouble de format espera el texto con el Locale que tu tengas definido.
Es posible que en un ejemplo lo tuvieras con Locale en ingles y en el otro en Español.
Si tu pones este codigo

```
 try {
            NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE); // usa . como el español.
            Number numero = format.parse("23,24");
            System.out.println("Numero frances: "+ numero.doubleValue());
        } catch (ParseException k)
        {
            System.out.println("Errro al cmabiar numero con Locale Frances");
        }
        try {
            // Asi no funciona
            NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
            Number numero = format.parse("23,24");
            System.out.println("Numero ingles: "+ numero.doubleValue());
        } catch (ParseException k)
        {
            System.out.println("Errro al cmabiar numero con Locale Ingles");
        }
```

Veras que la salida es la siguiente:

```
Numero frances: 23.24
Numero ingles: 2324.0
```

El caso es que la clase Double siempre usa el locale ingles, y en tu ejemplo da error en ambos casos.

Comment: he modificado la pregunta donde adjunto la prueba de que parsea correctamente siendo una ','

Comment: Y yo te he modificado la respuesta para que veas, que creo que  tiene que ver con el locale. De todos modos en la pregunta no se ve claro el tema, porque no veo donde da error o que ;-) Pero vamos, yo he creado un programa copiando y pegando lo que tu has puesto y casca en ambos casos.

Comment: Puede ser que sea lo del Locale por que tengo un Framwork por encima que es el que me proporciona la cadena con el valor numérico, y creo que usa Number el framework y no double. De todas formas seguiré sin entender por que en el primer caso no me funciona y en el segundo sí, por que al fin y al cabo es lo mismo.

Comment: ¿Que framework usas?, por curiosidad...

Comment: Es un FrameWork de financiación privada, no puedo proporcionarte esa información, lo siento, pero gracias por lo del Locale, creo que me ha ayudado bastante a ver por donde van los tiros más o menos.

Comment: Ok. Ha sido un placer.